# Is there a way to "get" whatever was pressed from an alert dialog and change the value of something else?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm learning Android Studio and I have to create a TicTacToe program. The game itself works just fine, however, I also need to get user input to ask who goes first and what color (between two colors like red or black) the person that's going first would like to be.

I've gone through the documentation for AlertDialogs, and I just can't figure out how to, in layman's terms, do something like:

```
if (alert.getButtonPressed() == "X") {
firstLetter == "X"
}

else {
firstLetter == "O"
}
```

That isn't what it'd look like AT ALL I know, but I'm just trying to help you all understand what I'm trying to do here. I also need it to do something similar, but instead of setting the first letter, or who's going first to X/O, I also need to set the color of X/O based on who's going first wanted to be.

The code I'll be posting isn't the full program, but I'm hoping it can give you enough of the important stuff to help you understand what the program looks like overall. There's a lot more code than I'm showing, and again, the game works, I  want to add the ability to choose who's going first, X's or O's, and what color of the person going first will be. I'm not in any way shape or form begging for someone to just do this for me, I just want to know if in the context of my program it'll be possible to get whatever the user presses from an AlertDialog, and then change what letter goes first, and what the color of that letter will be.

If more code needs to be posted, let me know. I'm really trying not to sound like a college student looking for someone to solve all my problems and just hand me the answer, so if I do I apologize and I assure you that isn't the case. I'm fully willing and ready to edit and change this post with whatever's needed to help me understand this.

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        game = new TicTacToe( );
        Point size = new Point( );
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay( ).getSize( size );
        int w = size.x / TicTacToe.SIDE;
        ButtonHandler bh = new ButtonHandler( );
        tttView = new ButtonGridAndTextView( this, w, TicTacToe.SIDE, bh );
        tttView.setStatusText( game.result( ) );
        setContentView( tttView );
    }



    private class ButtonHandler implements View.OnClickListener { //this is the buttonhandler to put an X/O
        public void onClick( View v ) {
            for( int row = 0; row < TicTacToe.SIDE; row++ ) {
                for( int column = 0; column < TicTacToe.SIDE; column++ ) {
                    if( tttView.isButton( ( Button ) v, row, column ) ) {
                        int play = game.play( row, column );
                        if( play == 1 )
                            tttView.setButtonText( row, column, "O" );
                        else if( play == 2 )
                            tttView.setButtonText( row, column, "X" );
                        if( game.isGameOver( ) ) {
                            tttView.setStatusBackgroundColor( Color.RED );
                            tttView.enableButtons( false );
                            tttView.setStatusText( game.result( ) );
                            showNewGameDialog( );    // offer to play again
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}




//Next bit of code is from my TicTacToe.java class

    public int play( int row, int col ) {
        int currentTurn = turn;
        if( row >= 0 && col >= 0 && row < SIDE && col < SIDE
                && game[row][col] == 0 ) {
            game[row][col] = turn;
            if( turn == 1 )
                turn = 2;
            else
                turn = 1;
            return currentTurn;
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I still don't see the `AlertDialog` object used anywhere?! Please tell me are you using it or TLDR kinda summary on do you want to get the value from alertDialog?

Comment: Well, the thing is that I want to use it. I tested it by just making an AlertDialog that does nothing, however, my issue is that I don't know how to get the AlertDialog to change the value of who's going first and what the color of the letter that's going first will be.

Comment: I can help you with getting the value of the alertDialog by implementing a custom Dialog class or using a library. Whatever suits you better.

Comment: A library sounds more straight forward and like it'd take less of your time, so that option seems best.

Comment: Why not use two global variables for _turn_ and _color_ , set them from inside your dialog and then load your game after checking these variables?

Comment: Would I be able to do that without having to rework my ButtonHandler?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs Check this out. It serves your purpose. No need to reinvent wheel.

Answer (score 0):

//TRY THIS

```
String[] YOURCHOICE = {"X", "O"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Choose your action!");
    builder.setItems(YOURCHOICE, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if(which == 0){
                //Do Some X function
            }else if(which == 1){
                //Do Some O function
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
```

Comment: You are comparing an int to a string